# isProduction method is not detected in "$this->app->isProduction()" in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am currently facing a really odd bug where I am trying to add preventLazyLoading restriction in a laravel project. But the thing is I followed the laravel docs on how to configure laravel strictness and implemented the restriction. And, I even ran "php artisan config:clear" command to make sure the configuration is taking in effect. But the thing is when I use the conditional default global method of "$this->app->isProduction()" the laravel does not detect the isProduction() method. I have never encountered it before. Please if you have any idea on how to solve the problem, share the suggestion below. I really appreciate you for reading this forum.

app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Model::preventLazyLoading(! $this->app->isProduction());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an error ? What do you mean by not detected ?

Comment: I have checked the Application.php inside the project and I can confirm that there is isProduction() method but for some reason laravel cannot detect the function. I am using Visual Studio Code and it is highlight red on the isProduction method. I also cannot ctrl +  click on the production name.

Comment: I think the problem here is the IDE or Plugin not the laravel.

Comment: What is the error? You need to explain what is not working... Vistual Studio Code saying it does not exist means nothing as `$this->app` has a reference to an interface but the interface does not have `isProduction` but the instance does... What errors do you have?

Comment: That's right I also try it in my VScode and its  also saying its undefined but if you run your application there is no error in it.

Comment: If you really want to remove the red line under it you can just use doc block to type hint it. you can just `$app = $this->app` and then add a doc block at the top of it like `@var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app` something like that.

Comment: Oh sorry guys! It definitely might be just VS Code highlighting undefined to the "isProduction". There seem to be no error at all. Thank you very much for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$this->app` refers to the `\Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider` **contract**. But the method `isProduction()` does not exist there.

Laravel resolves this to the `\Illuminate\Foundation\Application` **class**, which does have the `isProduction()` method.

So what you can do, is type-hint a variable, something like:

```php
    public function boot(): void
    {
        /** @var \Illuminate\Foundation\Application $app */
        $app = $this->app;

        Model::preventLazyLoading(!$app->isProduction());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, for answering the problem. I noticed that even though the IDE did not detect the isProduction method, laravel still works fine and detects and warns the lazy loading  error. It was honestly my mistake that there was an error in the first place.

Comment: I  think it's cleaner to use `app()->isProduction()` instead.

Comment: That is your opinion, I always prefer dependency injection.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble guys! It seem to be just VS Code IDE saying undefined and highlighting it. But the project does not seem to have any problem. The restriction also works too.